# Override mail settings in application for dev server environments

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am currently in the finishing stages of building an application and have asked the user group to perform production-level usage testing on the application.  My application is a makeshift order management system that sends an email to a customer when an order is saved that includes an invoice.

I ran into a problem yesterday when I was doing some testing; this environment currently contains production-quality data, including old customer records.  I processed a few orders and forgot about the functionality, and the customer who I did the orders for received emails saying the order is complete.  Good that it worked, bad that it lead to this confusion.

The action I would prefer would be to set something somewhere within the application that forces all emails, regardless of the to recipient, to be sent to a specific address, though I would settle for simply being able to turn it off for this application alone.  Turning it off on the server level is available not a preferred option due to the need to perform testing on other applications that process email, but are not populated with production-quality data.

Are there any specific flags or code I can use to override server settings in the application to only send email to a certain address based on how we identify our environment, or to not send email altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution presumes you use the same mail server but just want to swap emails to a test address (perhaps yours, so you can see the result). It also presumes your live server name resolves to something that has 'www.something.somethong.' and your dev/test/qa etc servers do not.

In your Application cfc onApplicationStart() try this:

```
<cfscript>
  if(listFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME,'.') != 'www') {
    Application.szEmailToTestEnv = 'test@somewhere.com'; // Use your test email here
  }
</cfscript>
```

Then where you send the email have a bit of logic infront of your mail param such that:

```
<cfscript>
  if(isDefined('Application.szEmailToTestEnv') && len(Application.szEmailToTestEnv)) {
    Variables.szEmailTo = Application.szEmailToTestEnv;
  } else Variables.szEmailTo = Variables.qCustomerEmail;
</cfscript>
```

And then in your cfmail:

```
<cfmail to="#Variables.szEmailTo#"....
```

Adjust scopes and variable names and value as necessary.
Essentially, any 'site' (say dev.yoursite.com) that is not your live site will then use the test email you set at app startup to send the email and live will continue to use the correct customer email with no code changes between your live and test code.

Comment: Not all the conditions you have are true for me, but I can modify this code to accommodate my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Reference this page:
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_can_I_use_Application_level_SMTP_Server_Settin-16469.html

For testing purposes you could set the SMTP server to a non existant IP address.  The cfmail routine will still work and coldfusion will move it to an undeliverable folder.

You could add `<cfif>` statements around it to determine if your on a production URL or dev URL so that it uses the right server while on the production server, or uses the "fake" server while on your development server.  OR while on the production server, have an on/off variable that you could use to test emails through your smtp server or shut off emails and route them to the fake SMTP server.

If your on version 8.0 or older, you can setup an application level variable for your mail server and modify your cfmail tags to reference:

```
<cfmail server="#application.mailserver#" to="" from="" subject="">
```

Comment: While William's solution is more appropriate for my problem, I like this solution as well and can imagine myself or someone else using it in different circumstances.